# How to set a Marketing List as the recipients in an email in a Custom Workflow?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

We're using Marketing Lists as a sort of "distribution list" as one of the options for email recipients in a Custom Workflow.
How does one go about setting the members of the Marketing List as the recipients?

I am able to get the List Entity, but am unsure of how to turn that into the `ActivityParty` that an Email requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set marketing list as email receiver. I had the same situation and my solution was to create custom workflow activity which will receive marketing list as input parameter. Then you read all members from list and send email to every one of them. ([Example how to read list members](http://lazarus987.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/how-to-retrieve-contacts-from-marketing-list-using-crm-2011-sdk-3/))

After that you can use that custom WF activity in dialog (for example) which will be executed on marketing list entity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can get the List Entity, but where do I go from there? There's a `user_list` property, but it appears to return only one `SystemUser` instead of an actual list.

Comment: Check [this example](http://lazarus987.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/how-to-retrieve-contacts-from-marketing-list-using-crm-2011-sdk-3/). Just exclude this condition 'if entity is Contact'. Hope it will help